# Установка библиотек Python с помощью APT

Tags: python, ubuntu

Имеется библиотека для Python. На данный момент её можно установить с помощью pip или conda. Можно ли сделать самому, чтобы была возможность устанавливать её через apt-get? Имеется скачанная в формате whl.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык

Comment: Сделал, за раннее благодарю.

Comment: Не думаю что вы сможете устанавливать пакеты одного менеджера, в другом. Да и зачем?

Comment: @HRLDeveloper, уже разобрался с созданием репозитория, осталось выяснить как имеющийся модуль собрать в .deb.

Comment: Попробуй https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm